# css background-image not appearing, how to solve without using min-height

Tags: css

How do I make my `background-image` show up without using `min-height: 200px;`? If I remove this line the `background-image` will not appear. I do not want to use `min-height: 200px`, as I am trying to make my site responsive the `min-height` thing will affect the different devices used, I wish to set the `height` to `auto` but it's not working.

```
header
{
    background-image:
    url(page_home/section_header.jpg),
    url(page_home/section_header_bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
    background-position: center, left;
    min-height:200px;
}
```

Comment: If you are setting a background image to an element, that element needs to have either height: or min-height: set on it.

Comment: If the header has no content it will have no height...if you need it to have a bg image, it must have height. How you achieve the height is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - you must set height or min-height so the element will be shown, but if you want a responsive site you can use different heights for different resolutions:

```
header
{
    background-image:
    url(page_home/section_header.jpg),
    url(page_home/section_header_bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
    background-position: center, left;
    height:200px;
}

/* #### Mobile Phones Portrait #### */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait){
  header
  {
    height:400px;
  }
}

/* #### Mobile Phones Landscape #### */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) and (orientation: landscape){
  header
  {
    height:250px;
  }
}

/* #### Mobile Phones Portrait or Landscape #### */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px){
  header
  {
    height:100px;
  }
}
```

More about max-device-width:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml

Also you may want to read about bootstrap - a JS framework for developing responsive sites for web and mobile: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: i've read about it, but i found an alternative that seem easier for me, i'm currently using 'skeleton' from http://www.getskeleton.com/ to make my site responsive. So far the responsiveness is working fine, just that when it got scaled down to mobile size the bg-image is still stuck at 200px height that i set, i will try out your method and report back. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

CSS3 has a property background-size.

```
header { 
  background: url(page_home/section_header.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

You still have to give it a height or min-height, I don't think there is an alternative

Comment: Nice! But it works only for IE9 and above - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp